# Finding the splitting field for $x^4 + x$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

I've found the roots (with help from wolframalpha): $x = 0$, $x = -1$, $x = $e^i\pi/3$, $x = -(-1)^{2/3}$.

But I don't know how to express it in the form $\mathbb Q(a)$, where $a$ is some real or complex number.

Comment: First you want to express it as a product of irreducibles, $x(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, and since the first two factors already have their roots in $\Bbb Q$, you only need to adjoin a root of the third factor to get your field.

Comment: Would that be Q(e^ipi/3)? I can imagine getting -(-1)^2/3 through field operations on e^ipi/3, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to think of it as $\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As the polynomial factors as $\;x(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, it's the same as the splitting field of the quadratic polynomial $x^2-x+1$, , which has well-known roots.

Comment: Right. I have all the roots, but I don't know how to find one element to adjoin with Q to include all of them. 0 and 1 are "for free" in that they're already contained in Q, but I don't know what element would give me the other two roots.

Comment: @user495422: any root of $x^2-x+1=0$, which are $-j$ and $-j^2$ ($j$ and $j^2$ are the non-real cube roots of unity).

Answer (score 0):

The zeros are $0$, $-1$, $\exp(\pi i/3)$ and $\exp(-\pi i/3)$, that is
$0$, $-1$, $\zeta$ and $\zeta^{-1}$ for $\zeta=\exp(\pi i/3)$. So they generate the field $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$.